# How to use language change strings.xml in values-v21?

Tags: java, android, xml

If I use **`strings.xml`** for hindi language in **`values-hi`** in `res` then it doesn't work .
If I use **`strings.xml`** for hindi language in **`values-v21`** in `res` then it  works, but by default the app selects hindi language.
Then I am unable to come back in english. What can I have to do for that?

Comment: Check if the system is getting another resource using the Best-matching Resource: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Answer (score 0):

- change `values` to `values-hi`
- I have done by adding `values-hi`

---

[image]

Comment: Then where are you putting the english strings.xml which is in values folder?

Comment: you want to set `default` if yes then you have to do change in `values` to `values-hi`

Comment: No i want both language. Default language will be english. Here my problem is "values-hi" directory is not effecting in my app when i change the system language into hindi.

Comment: you've to remove `values-hi` then it would be english `make another` directory named as `values-hi`

Comment: it will only changes your app's language it does not affect your system language